# How to refer to a resource not in the Library Project, but only in the dependent Application Project?

Tags: android, library-project

I'm turning my one app into several similar apps and using a base library project. I want to load a video that will be in `res/raw/welcome.m4a` in the dependent applications.

This is how is was being done before using the library project:

```
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.welcome));
```

This produces an error in my library project, because `res/raw/welcome.m4v` doesn't exist, it will only be in the App Project `res/` folder, and will be different for each app.

My current workaround is to create a dummy `res/raw/welcome.m4v` in the base library project so it stops complaining.

So my question is how do I have code in the Library Project that refers to resources that don't exist in the Library Project?

Comment: I recommend having the hosting application pass in the path to be used to your library project. IMHO, the library project should neither know nor care where the video is: raw resource, local file, `rtsp` URL, `http` URL, etc.

Comment: How would I do this? The activity code itself is in the Library Project. I would need to configure this externally to the activity. Would I do it in the strings file?

Comment: Somewhere, the host project needs to be connected to this library. Wherever that is, pass the value. For example, put it as an extra on the `Intent` used to pass control to this activity from the library.

Comment: I have a similar problem (with the difference that I do not know the name of the movie beforehand) and trying exactly what CommonsWare is suggesting: make an Intent with a `Uri` that is created like pixelearth does in his question, with the package name of the dependent app, but I get 'unable to open content' when trying to play the movie within code of the library. A working code example would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If it is only happening infrequently, you can try this:

```
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+getResources().getIdentifier("welcome", "raw", getPackageName())));
```

Not as performant as using the id, but it should work.